# Rails - How to mock or access methods defined in ApplicationController from helper spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to write specs for a Rails helper. This helper calls a method 
defined in `ApplicationController` and exposed through `helper_method`:

**app/helpers/monkeys_helper.rb**:

```
module MonkeysHelper
  def current_monkey_banana_count
    # current_monkey is defined in ApplicationController
    current_monkey.present? ? current_monkey.banana_count : 0 
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base   
  helper_method :current_monkey

  protected

  def current_monkey
    @current_monkey ||= Monkey.find(session[:monkey_id])
  end
end
```

If I call `current_monkey_banana_count` from a view and access it through the browser, it works fine. But if I call it from a spec like this:

**spec/helpers/monkeys_helper_spec.rb**:

```
RSpec.describe MonkeysHelper, type: :helper do
  describe "#current_monkey_banana_count" do
    it "returns 0 if there is no monkey" do
      expect(helper.current_monkey_banana_count).to eq 0
    end
  end
end
```

Then I get this error when I run the spec:

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `current_monkey' for #<#<Class:0x007fe1ed38d700>:0x007fe1e9c72d88>
```

[Rspec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec) says:

> To access the helper methods you're specifying, simply call them
>   directly on the helper object. NOTE: helper methods defined in
>   controllers are not included.

Any idea how to either mock `current_monkey` or make it visible from inside `current_monkey_banana_count`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a (nasty) way to do it, but it works:

**spec/helpers/monkeys_helper_spec.rb:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CartsHelper, type: :helper do
  before do
    def helper.current_monkey; end
  end

  describe "#current_monkey_banana_count" do
    it "returns 0 if there is no cart" do
      expect(helper).to receive(:current_monkey).and_return(nil)
      expect(helper.current_monkey_banana_count).to eq 0
    end

    it "returns monkey.banana_count if there is a monkey" do
      expect(helper).to receive(:current_monkey).and_return(Monkey.create!(banana_count: 5))
      expect(helper.current_monkey_banana_count).to eq 5
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve that by mocking `current_monkey` in this way (have you tried it already?):

```
RSpec.describe MonkeysHelper, type: :helper do
  let(:monkey) { create(:monkey) }

  before do
    allow(helper).to receive(:current_monkey_user) { monkey }
  end

  # your rest of code
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately this fails with `<Helper ...> does not implement: current_monkey`. Apparently you cannot mock a method that is not defined :(

Answer (score 0):

View can call helper methods defined in controller because controller eval them automatically, please check code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5db73076914e7103466bd76bec785cbcfe88875/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb#L60).

But your helper test doesn't call controller, so that `current_monkey` isn't available on `MonkeysHelper` module. The best practice is helpers defined in controller call helper defined in helper class but not vice versa. In your case, you can move current_monkey to MonkeyHelper to be able to test it.

Comment: `current_monkey` uses the `session` object which is not available within helpers, so I can't move it to `MonkeyHelper`.